# How to get firmware version in TI's CC2541?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Greetings of the day,

I want to know the current firmware version which I built using IAR how to get that information more specifically I want know all the **DEVICE INFORMATION SERVICE**.

With thanks and regards

Jayaraj

Answer (score 1):

You can access the source code and all documentation from TI BLE stack (current version 1.4) from following site:

http://www.ti.com/tool/ble-stack